# I need to retrieve the date from the row that will deplete my inventory

Tags: excel, inventory

This is hard to explain...

I have a report that I pull from our MRP system that gives me a Due-Date, a quantity required, and an item number. There will usually be several rows with the same item number each representing a different sales order.
I have another report that gives me the on hand quantity for each item. In this report, each item is listed only once.

I need to get the Due-Date that corresponds to the row that will use up the last of my inventory. (Inv. runout)

| Due-Date | QTY-REQ | ITEM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/27/21 | 5 | C |
| 4/28/21 | 7 | A |
| 4/29/21 | 5 | B |
| 4/30/21 | 1 | B |
| 5/1/21 | 13 | A |
| 5/2/21 | 4 | A |
| 5/3/21 | 12 | C |
| 5/4/21 | 1 | A |

| OHQ | ITEM | INV. RUNOUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | formula here, Result should be 5/1/21 |
| 5 | B | result should be 4/30/21 |
| 10 | C | result should be 5/3/21 |

I hope this makes sense, if not, please let me know what I can answer to help with this.

-Nick

Comment: Since this is not a free code-writing service, but rather exists to help with code or complex formulas you are trying to develop, it is expected that you show what you have done to try to solve this problem on your own, and the issues those attempts have revealed.

Comment: Hi Ron, I understand completely. I’ve just tried so many different failed approaches I wasn’t sure if any of them would be helpful. I think I’m getting closer and hopefully I’ll be able to post a solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a new column on the first report using `IF(SUMIFS(` to only show the date of lines where the stock runs out at or before that date. Then in the second report, use `MINIFS()`, a fairly new function, to find the earliest date in that column that matches each product.
In the below example I'm assuming that both of the above reports shown are columns A B and C, in the same excel file, on sheets called Report1 and Report2.

In cell Z2 on Report1, enter the formula `IF(SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, "<=" & A2, C:C, C2) > INDEX(Report2!A:A,MATCH(Report1!C2,Report2!B:B,0)), A2, "")` and copy down for all rows. This will only display the date where the stock has run out by that date.

In cell C2 on Report2, enter the formula `=MINIFS(Report1!Z:Z, Report1!C:C, Report2!B2)` to get the earliest relevant date displayed from the formula above.

Comment: Hi Spencer, This looks like a simplified version of what I was getting to. (My version involved about 5 more columns) I can’t wait to try it tomorrow, thank you!